# Angular 2 - dropdown value to replace default when selected

Tags: angular, select, dropdown

I have select with one default and rest ngFor generated options.

```
<select (change)="loadStart($event.target.value); value="">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Select start</option>
    <option *ngFor="let s of starts" [value]=s.name>{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
```

When I select some of s from list, it works great, but I can't set it to replace default "Select start" when I select it from option.

Comment: "but I can't set it to replace default "Select start" when I select it from option" - can't really understand that, can you explain what you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Buczkowski If i generate with ngFor lets say [1,2,3,4] and then i select from dropdown 4, that works ok, but stil in my dropdown field is showing Select start instead 4

Comment: that is because select start is selected by default and the attribute is never removed .